# Flutter migration from Windows to Mac

Tags: macos, flutter, migration

I have developed a Flutter Mobile application on Windows 10 environment. I am using Firebase with services like Firestore, push notifications, storage and Authentication.

I have not done anything for IOS so far. I am planning to have a Mac machine in cloud and start the IOS related changes there. I have below questions.

1. I want to have my code at both the places synced so that I can work on windows and Mac. Is there any way to do that securely?
2. What editor I should use on Mac for IOS and Android development?

Also what are the other things I need to take care?

Thank you in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**for syncing:**
git, period! Flutter will take care of the rest

**for IDE:**
we swear by Intellij as you will need it if you decide to port an android version of your app. With Intellij you can even sync plugins & IDE settings across multiple PCs